# How to query values from related arrays in PHP and display them in HTML table

Tags: sql, select, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-table

The following two-dimensional array stores information for books (1.ID, 2.Name, 3.Author ID, 4.Author Name, 5.Publisher ID, 6. Publisher Name, 7. Publisher Reputation):

```
$books = array(array('book_id'=>1, 'book_name'=>"BookA", 'author_id'=1, 
                     'author_name'=>"AuthorA", 'publisher_id'=>1,   
                     'publisher_name'=>"PublisherA", 'publisher_reputation'="good"),
               array('book_id'=>1, 'book_name'=>"BookA", 'author_id'=1, 
                     'author_name'=>"AuthorA", 'publisher_id'=>2,   
                     'publisher_name'=>"PublisherB", 'publisher_reputation'="bad")
               array('book_id'=>1, 'book_name'=>"BookA",  'author_id'=>2, 
                     'author_name'=>"AuthorB", 'publisher_id'=>1
                     'publisher_name'=>"PublisherA", 'publisher_reputation'=>"good"),
               array('book_id'=>1, 'book_name'=>"BookA",  'author_id'=>2, 
                     'author_name'=>"AuthorB", 'publisher_id'=>2
                     'publisher_name'=>"PublisherB", 'publisher_reputation'=>"bad"),
```

A book can have several authors and several publishers.
An author can be associated with several books.
A publisher can be associated with several books.
A publisher can only have one reputation (from list of values: "good","average","bad").

EDIT: The data are stored in 3 tables. author (author_id, author_name), book (book_id, book_name), publisher (publisher_id, publisher_name, publisher_reputation).

I would like to create an HTML table with the following columns:

1. Book Name - Field lists specific book.
2. Author(s) - Field lists all authors associated with the book.
3. Publisher & Reputation - Field lists all publishers (and their reputations) associated with this book.

I am currently using the following code:

```
<?php function transform($books) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($books as $key => $book) {
            $book_id = $book['book_id'];
                if (!isset($result[$book_id])) {
                $result[$book_id] = array(
                        'author_name' => array(),
                        'publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation' => array(),
                            'book_name' => $book['book_name']
                );        
                }
         $result[$book_id]['publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation'] = 
         array_merge($result[$book_id]['publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation'], 
         array(($book['publisher_name'].'('.$book['publisher_reputation'].')'))); 
         $result[$book_id]['author_name'] = array_merge($result[$book_id] 
         ['author_name'], array(($book['author_name'])));
         }

         foreach($result as $key => $data) {
         $result[$key]['publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation'] = 
         array_unique($result[$key]['publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation']);
         $result[$key]['author_name'] = array_unique($result[$key]['author_name']);
         }
         return $result;
         }

$books = transform($books)
;?>
```

My html code to create the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Author(s)</th>
        <th>Publisher(s) & Reputation(s)</th>
    </tr>

<?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php htmlout($book['book_name']); ?></td> 
    <td><?php foreach(($book['author_name']) as $author_name): ?>
        <?php htmlout($author_name);?><br /><?php endforeach; ?></td>
    <td><?php foreach(($book['publisher_name'.'publisher_reputation']) as    
          $publisher_namereputation): ?></td>
        <?php htmlout($publisher_namereputation);?><br /><?php endforeach; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Resulting table (Table 1.):

```
Book Name       | Author(s)        | Publisher(s) & Reputation(s)
BookA             AuthorA            PublisherA(good)
                  AuthorB            PublisherB(bad)
```

- As desired: When I query "all books by AuthorA (WHERE author_id=1)," I get the above result.
- As desired: When I query "all books published by PublisherA (WHERE publisher_id=1)," I get the above result.
- **Problem:** When I query "all books published by a publisher with reputation = good (WHERE publisher_reputation = "good")," I get the following result:

Table 2.:

```
Book Name       | Author(s)        | Publisher(s) & Reputation(s)
BookA             AuthorA            PublisherA(good)
                  AuthorB
```

PublisherB, who is also associated with the very same book(but has a "bad" reputation) is not displayed. I do understand that this is because the reputation was chosen from a list ("good", "average", "bad") whose values are not associated with any individual publisher_id (several publishers can have the same reputation). I tried to solve the problem by preparing the reputation list in the following way:

```
try
{
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT publisher_id, publisher_reputation FROM publisher');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching publisher reputation information!';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $reputations[] = array('publisher_id' => $row['publisher_id'],
    'publisher_reputation' => $row['publisher_reputation']);
}
(...)
```

However, this gives me a list of reputations with repeated values (when several publishers with the same reputation are in the database).

**Question:** How can I design a query that returns Table 1 when I search for all book_names that are associated with a publisher_name with publisher_reputation = good?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the full view. When I look around whatever you have posted, I came across a thing that you have missed to close a paranthesis in the line "$result = $pdo->query(...."

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are 3 tables in your database which are - 
1) Books -> stores books related information with foreign key as publisherId
2) Publisher -> stores publisher related informatino where publisherId is PK
3) Reputation -> kind of HREF table b/w books and publisher with both tables PK as FK.

If i guess right than you can consider following query -

> SELECT * FROM books as B
>   INNER JOIN publisher as P on P.publisherId = B.publisherId
>   INNER JOIN reputation as R on (R.publisherId = B.publisherId AND R.publisherId = 
>   P.publisherId) WHERE R.Reputation ="GOOD"

Comment: Yes, the information is stored in 3 tables. However, these tables are: author(author_id, author_name), book (book_id, book_name), publisher (publisher_id, publisher_name, publisher_reputation).

Comment: Thanks for information than you can change in my above query accordingly, hopefully you will get desired answer.

Please mark answer right if you seems answer helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks Varun. However, this still does not return the desired result. Just for clarification: I have the author, book, and publisher tables. Those are connected through linking tables authorbook(PK=(FK=author_id, FK=book_id)) and publisherbook (PK=(FK=publisher_id, FK=book_id)).